# Disabling excess services on Windows Web Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, webserver, services

I'm running a development VM on my notebook with Windows Web Server 2008 R2 operating system. To save some resources and gain some speed I'm thinking about disabling some services:

- Microsoft Software Shadow Copy Provider
- Print Spooler
- Remote Registry
- Windows Remote Management

Why would I disable them? Because I don't think they're beneficial and slow disk operation down while also consuming memory resources.

Should I consider other services as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The VSS service is usually only used for backups and related activities.
- The Print Spooler I regularly disable on servers where I never print.
- Remote Registry is only needed if you're going to be editing the registry remotely.
- Remote Management, same as Remote Registry.

There are guides on the net concerning which services are "safe" to disable. If you're really low on resources however, you're draining the ocean one bucket at a time.

Comment: Can you provide a link? and BTW: It's seems interesting that there is no *Indexing Service* nor is there *Windows Search* or similar that do disk indexing. But there is the checkbox in disk properties to disable indexing... Which service uses it then?

Comment: VSS is also required for the Previous Versions function to work.

Comment: @afrazier: can you elaborate on that? Who uses that and is that part of any service?

Comment: Previous Versions is MS's name for block-level point-in-time snapshots of the filesystem.  If enabled on the system, they can be accessed from the properties of any file or folder on the system.  Also, you may not be seeing the Search services if the feature isn't enabled on the server.

Comment: See the table at the bottom of this page: http://www.blackviper.com/2009/10/13/black-vipers-windows-server-2008-r2-service-configurations/ You wont find Search/Indexer service unless you installed that Role.